# Redirect location comes from browser cache. Cookie modification not applied

Tags: php, redirect, kohana

I use KO3.1 & php 5.3.3

In my controller 'action_lang' with route 'lang/code' I set user UI language and save it into the cookie with:

```
Cookie::set('language', $code)
```

Right after this I call:

```
Request::current()->redirect('/')
```

to move to the main page, where I have

```
echo Cookie::get('language')
```

to print current language.

The problem is my browser reads redirected page from it's CACHE thus Cookie::get('language') always shows the SAME value. The only way is to force the browser to refresh with F5, then it change as expected but that's not the way it should work. / It should change instantly!

Is there something wrong with this method? or its just me too tired...
I'm sure this worked fine some time ago, with the very same browser and KO2.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beahvior of the browser might actually correct, if the cache headers indicate it. The correct solution would be to forbid caching of the URI contents. However, some browsers have issues here and it might not be desired to not allow the browser caching the URL at all.

A simple solution to fool the browsers for reloading the page in your exact case is to append a random parameter to the URL like `?refresh=$time` with `$time` being the current time stamp.

Comment: So how php's session works? It stores session ID in the cookie also. Isn't it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHPs session. If the browser thinks the content can be cached it does not send a request to the server at all and just displays the content. Therefore, changes are not visible.